# Stopping a For Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

What I am trying to do is getting rid of the + sign after the ending value from the user inputs.

```
count = 0
total = 0

# Input
start = int(float(input("1 of 2 - Enter Starting Loop Value: ")))
ending = int(float(input("2 of 2 - Enter Ending Loop Value: ")))

# for loop
for n in range(start, ending+1, 1):
  total = total + n
  count = count + 1
  print(n, "+ ", end="")
print("=", total)

print("\nLoop ran", count, "Times")

print("\n\n")
```

The output would look like..

```
1 of 2 - Enter Starting Loop Value: 5
2 of 2 - Enter Ending Loop Value: 11
5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + = 56

Loop ran 7 Times
```

So I would like to get rid of the + after the 11.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to make sure you're only printing when it's not the last number to be printed, like this.

```
for n in range(start, ending+1, 1):
  total = total + n
  count = count + 1
  if n != ending:
      print(n, "+ ", end="")
  else:
      print(n + " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
nums = list(range(start,ending+1))
total = sum(nums)
strsum = ' + '.join(str(i) for i in nums)
print('{} = {}'.format(strsum,total))
```